# Is the 'Heaven' in Miner's Heaven meant literally?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I've installed the [Miner's Heaven mod](http://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/152forgecopy-miners-heaven---dimensions-tools-and-more/) for Minecraft 1.7.2 (Forge). Finally, after <strike>methodically exploring every dungeon in the game</strike> cheating one in *after* methodically exploring every dungeon I could find, I managed to get my hands on a portal igniter. I placed my diamond block, lit it up and *boom*, I had a portal.

Stepping through the portal, no matter *where* in the overworld I place one, results in me landing directly in cobblestone and suffocating. I tried a hundred blocks away from where I first placed it, then a few hundred blocks away, then a few thousand blocks away, and then as far as the far lands. I keep going straight to Miner's Heaven, literally.

On me, I had:

- Some [telepads](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1292377-1-7-ssp-smp-telepads-taking-teleports-to-a-whole)
- A [telepebble](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1293781-1-7-2-forge-utilities3-power-conversion-and-fluid)
- An angel ring from extra utilities
- Misc IC2 mining supplies

So I tried alternating / dropping what was in my inventory (the telepebble saved me from death until the last try, when I went in my birthday suit).

Attempts to mine my way out of wherever it sent me weren't successful. It's like I was sent into the middle of a *very* big rock.

Is this a known glitch? Punishment for bringing in an igniter from creative mode so I could test my mod pack? Are certain things in inventory supposed to cause weird behavior (e.g. the crystal dimension removed all your stuff).

I've run out of things to try, what else can I do to get this mod to work like it's (apparently) working for everyone else?

Comment: mining down twice should drop you into an air hole

Comment: @ratchetfreak Turns out, I was a good ~100 blocks into stone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to say about the portal placement, it will always return to the same spot, the portals don't work like nether portals it is just one location, confirmed by users on the site you linked. This is not intentional and the mod maker is looking into it.

*an example*

> Nice mod. I set everything up went poof to the Mining world and returned. Decided I did not like the placement of my source portal so I moved it. However everytime I return I return to the place it used to be. Is there a way to change where I return?

I have checked the change logs and as yet there is no fix for this.

Chances are you have spawned in the wall, you will need to dig until you find a cave network, I would say dig straight down (with caution) as i believe there is no surface.

Comment: Mining a block is rather hard when you are suffocating in cobblestone.

Comment: I presumed as he is testing and said he gave himself something in creative that he could pop into creative for it.

Comment: @Arperum even so with efficiency on a diamond pick or some other mod tools you could easily mine the block at your head level

Comment: So, the work-around being, go into creative, go through the portal and _start punching for your very life even though you're now immortal_. Suddenly, heaven doesn't sound like such a boring place any longer :)

Comment: What's also interesting, is, if you build the portal in the vicinity of a nether portal (mine was about 150 blocks away), another nether portal will appear next to your newly built portal. Weird. That's what made me think to try moving it.